# How to recalculate position, when copy template

Tags: xslt

I want to ask how to recalculate line number position and other data when I copy template  from another xml file if satisfy condition that code should be the same like in lookup.xml.

My programs look like that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>   
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="Line-Item[code = document('lookup.xml')/*/*/code]" />
    <xsl:template match="Line[not(Line-Item/code[not(. = document('lookup.xml')/*/*/code ) ] )]"/>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml file:

```
<document>
    <header>
        <remarks>test</remarks>
    </header>
    <Line>
        <Line-Item>
            <lineNumb>1</lineNumb>
            <code>123</code>
            <amount>4</amount>
        </Line-Item>
        <Line-Item>
            <lineNumb>2</lineNumb>
            <code>444</code>
            <amount>2</amount>
        </Line-Item>
        <Line-Item>
            <lineNumb>3</lineNumb>
            <code>321</code>
            <amount>1</amount>
        </Line-Item>
    </Line>
    <summary>
        <total-line>3</total-line>
        <total-amount>7</total-amount>
    </summary>
</document>
```

Lookup.xml file:

```
<lookup>
    <Codes>
        <code>123</code>
    </Codes>
</lookup>
```

I need recalculate lineNumb in Line-Item, And summary there is total-line and total-amount.

Correct result:

```
<document>
    <header>
        <remarks>test</remarks>
    </header>
    <Line>
        <Line-Item>
            <lineNumb>1</lineNumb>
            <code>444</code>
            <amount>2</amount>
        </Line-Item>
        <Line-Item>
            <lineNumb>2</lineNumb>
            <code>321</code>
            <amount>1</amount>
        </Line-Item>
    </Line>
    <summary>
        <total-line>2</total-line>
        <total-amount>3</total-amount>
    </summary>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is almost done. You need only  XPath `count()` and `sum()`. To recalculate the `lineNumb`, I've counted all previous sibling elements but the ones matching the lookup code.

I think this should work fine on the base of your assumptions.

---

**XSLT 1.0** tested on **Saxon-B 9.0.0.4J**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>   

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Line">

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Line-Item"/>
        </xsl:copy>

        <xsl:variable name="lines" select="count(Line-Item[not(code = document('lookup.xml')/*/*/code)])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="amount" select="sum(Line-Item[not(code = document('lookup.xml')/*/*/code)]/amount)"/>

        <summary>
            <total-line><xsl:value-of select="$lines"/></total-line>
            <total-amount><xsl:value-of select="$amount"/></total-amount>
        </summary>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Line-Item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <lineNumb>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[not(code = document('lookup.xml')/*/*/code)])+1"/>
            </lineNumb>
            <xsl:copy-of select="code"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="amount"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Line-Item[code = document('lookup.xml')/*/*/code]|summary" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, but lineNumb doesn't recalculate. I mean lineNumb position=2 and 3, then should be 1 and 2, because first we delete.

Comment: I'm sorry, didnt see that particular :). I'll try it asap.

Comment: The answer now includes the `lineNumb` recalculation. Hope it's what you need.